# i have to display the records which are not in "timecard" table

Tags: mysql

i have to display the records which are not in "timecard" table.The table contains following columns-

```
tcID Primary int(11)                    
RequestID int(11)           
StaffID int(11)             
ShiftStartDate date             
ShiftEndDate date               
JobStartTime time           
JobEndTime time         
lunchTaken time         
ApprovalCode varchar(45)
```

Query:

```
SELECT *
FROM acceptedrequest ar
LEFT JOIN staff s ON s.StaffID = ar.StaffID
LEFT JOIN staffposition sp ON sp.PositionCode = s.PositionCode
WHERE
  ar.AgencyID = 0
  AND ar.RequestID = 2364
  and RepalceStatus = 0
  and ar.CancelStatus = 0
  and ar.BroadcastStatus = 0
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please provide more details like : all tables information and how they are associated.

If I assume acceptedrequest staff is not to be in timecard staff then,
Try following:

```
SELECT * FROM acceptedrequest ar
LEFT JOIN staff s ON s.StaffID = ar.StaffID  
LEFT JOIN staffposition sp ON sp.PositionCode = s.PositionCode 
WHERE ar.AgencyID = 0 
  AND ar.RequestID = 2364 
  AND RepalceStatus = 0 
  AND ar.CancelStatus = 0 
  AND ar.BroadcastStatus = 0  
  AND ar.staffID not in(SELECT staffID from timecard)
```

Hope it helps!!!

Comment: Thanks for the help.